# Placeholder gets clipped on input element when size attribute is set to its length

Tags: javascript, html, css

For an input element, I am setting placeholder containing 23 characters as below. Using CSS I am setting the font-size to 12px. In Javascript, I am setting the size attribute to the length of the placeholder to ensure that it is displayed completely.

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b37L4cmh/

Chrome(v121.0.6167.185):
[image]

As per HTML specification for [input size attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-size-attribute),

> The size attribute gives the number of characters that, in a visual rendering, the user agent is to allow the user to see while editing the element's value.

So, I would expect browser to ensure that full length of placeholder is visible with the above snippet, but it gets clipped.

When I change, the font-size to 13px or 11px, I am able to view the full text of placeholder.

**Update**
When font-size: 12px is applied to ::placeholder, the placeholder is completely displayed.
https://jsfiddle.net/phalgunv/yw6x9z80/4/
[image]

When font-size: 12px is applied to both the input element and the placeholder, the placeholder is clipped again.
https://jsfiddle.net/phalgunv/Lvfes2p5/4/
[image]

For the same snippet, Firefox(122.0.1) displays the full length of the placeholder. However, the text types in input gets clipped.
[image]
[image]

Questions:

1. Why is the placeholder getting clipped for `input {font-size: 12px}` in Chrome?(Unanswered)
2. How do I get both the placeholder and the input text to be visible at font-size:12px ?(Answered)

Comment: The font size used for the placeholder is determined by the browser unless it's been set using ::placeholder. If you look carefully at the placeholder string versus the same string typed in by the user you will see they are not the same length. Try setting the font-size of ::placeholder to 12px as well.

Comment: If font-size: 12px is applied to both input and ::placeholder the placeholder is clipped. However, when the font-size: 12px is set to only ::placeholder and not input, then placeholder is visible and the text I type also seems to be the same size as the placeholder. I have update the question with the same.

Comment: @AHaworth, you are right. When I set font-size for ::placeholder, the font-size of the text is different. The difference is more noticeable with upper case characters. Earlier, I was trying with digits.

Comment: unless you are working with a monospace font, taking the number of characters in the placeholder and just using that to set the width via the size attribute may or may not set it wide enough for the placeholder (I believe the system will use some sort of average character width to decide on how wide the input should be). To ensure no cutting off whatever the content of the text you need to set the width to actual placeholder text width.

Comment: I tried to set width to be equal to the length of placeholder text using "ch" as unit of length, but it does a few characters are still getting clipped. Here's what I tried
https://jsfiddle.net/phalgunv/Lvfes2p5/23/

Comment: You need to find the actual/real width of the placeholder text if you are using a variable font. The size attribute will work on avg. character widths, not the true width of the text and the same is the problem with using the ch unit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth) for the approach.

I've simplified the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015393/3423750 to find the actual width of placeholder text. This works across Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Here's the solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Placeholder visibility</title>
        <style>
            input {
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            ::placeholder {
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        />
        <script>
            const input = document.querySelector("input");
            const placeholderText = input.getAttribute("placeholder");

            const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(input);
            // Determine actual width of placeholder text
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.font =
                computedStyle.fontSize + " " + computedStyle.fontFamily;
            const textWidth = context.measureText(placeholderText).width;

            input.style.width =
                textWidth +
                parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingLeft) +
                parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingRight) +
                "px";
            canvas.remove();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Edge:
[image]